# How to auto destroy a DOM element after a specific time using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, timer

Is it possible to remove a HTML element after specified time?

Also if a condition satisfied in between the specified time, I need to stop the timer from removing the element.

Sample code,

```
<ul>
   <li  data-id="25">
      <a class="online">Marco</a>
   </li>
   <li  data-id="53">
      <a class="online busy">Polo</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

When the user Marco's goes offline, I need to remove the Marco's `<li>` after 10 secs but if he comes back online within 10 secs the timer should be stoped and `<li>` should not be removed.

Socket handles the user online status:

```
socket.on('user_connected', function(data){
   var uId = data['uId'];
   ///
});

socket.on('user_disconnected', function(data){
   var uId = data['uId'];
   ///
});
```

Can anybody please give me a generic solution to remove an element using the timer and stop the timer before removing the element?

Comment: where is the code that detects whether Macro is online?

Comment: look at [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) and [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a combination of setTimeout and clearTimeout.

```
var timers = { };

timers.marco = setTimeout(function() {
  $('ul > li').remove();
}, 10000);

// ...

if (user.isOnline) {
  clearTimeout(timers.marco);
}
```

The `setTimeout` function returns a reference to the timer, so storing the reference allows you to clear it at a later time.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! :) That was simple!!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using `setTimeout`

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function()
{
     $('*[data-id="25"]').remove();
},10000);
```

if you need to cancel the timeout just call

```
clearTimeout(timeout);
```

this is statically typed, but you can insert a variable in place for the data id just as well.. using marco as the specific example above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!!

I simply created a generic function with your help,

```
function auto_destroy(data)
{
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
            data['DOM'].fadeOut('fast',function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }, data['secs']);

    data['DOM'].data('destroy_timer', t);
}

function remove_destroy_timer(dom)
{
    clearTimeout(dom.data('destroy_timer'));
}
```

Comment: You should accept that answer that answered your question, and put your solution in your original post.